# Looking for a way to assign @ControllerAdvice to specific url path pattern or controllers

Tags: spring

I was looking for a way to make `@ControllerAdvice` to be called for only specific url path pattern or a group of controllers. So, I found I can create custom `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` and assign it to custom controllers by `setMappedHandlerClasses()`. The problem is, there is also a default ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver and it also picks up my `@ControllerAdvice`. So I end up with two `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`'s, both of them having handler defined in `@ControllerAdvice`-annotated class. So, while my custom  `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` isn't called on all beans, default one does. Probably the solution would be to remove `@ControllerAdvice` and manually assign custom `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` inside custom `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`. I tried last way, but it appeared that I have to override a lot of methods from `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` and in the end code looks very unclean. So, is there a way to make it in a different way, or maybe implement `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` with custom handler cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

Put the Exception handling method in the Controller class and annotated the method with `@ExceptionHandler`. So this handler will be used only by this controller. -- And of course remove the `@ControllerAdvice` stuff.

Comment: Yeah finally I did this. But because I'm spring noob, i thought that i'll be able to configure `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: In Spring 4.0 you will be able to assign an ControllerAdvice so some pagage or so, but this is not possible with 3.2 http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring 4.0 you can use

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {OneOfControllersToApply.class})
```